# Xml character encoding with UTF format

Tags: c#, xml

I am serializing c# object to Xml using below code.

```
public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.UTF8; } }
}

public string SerializeDataWithUTF8Encoding<T>(T data)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    StringWriter sw = new Utf8StringWriter();
    serializer.Serialize(sw, data);
    var xmlString = sw.ToString();
    return xmlString;
}
```

Using this code, i am serializing below object with static value as mentioned below.

```
public class Test
{
    string Description = "This is the charge in advance for your %quantity% Line isolating unit No. 1A at &#xA3;%quantity rate% per unit per month";
}

Test obj = new Test();

//calling above function
SerializeDataWithUTF8Encoding(obj)
```

but in the xml generated above, I am getting description as

"This is the charge in advance for your %quantity% Line isolating unit No. 1A at £%quantity rate% per unit per month".

So here `&#xA3;` is encoded as `£`.

How can I stop this encoding? I want to keep `&#xA3;` as is in the XML.

I have tried several options but not getting much help.

Comment: I've just tried your code, and I get quite the opposite result - I get XML containing `&amp;#xA3;` which is what I'd expect, as that's the XML representation of the *text* you've provided. It's escaping the `&` as it should be. Your description string is just text, as far as the XML serializer is concerned. It's not expecting it to already be XML-encoded. Why don't you just put `£` (or `\u00a3`) in your string, if you want it to include a pound sign?

Comment: i am expecting the same as your result but for me, with same code, its coming as pound sign.. i can't put pound sign as text is coming from third party and they want exactly the same text to be present in the xml. Thanks

Comment: Please show a short but complete console application demonstrating this then - my guess is that the problem is in how you're diagnosing it. Fundamentally, if the text should be propagated as XML directly with no encoding, you may have a problem. I don't know how you'd do that with XmlSerializer, given that its job is to represent the text it's given within XML...